# How can I find the data between two specific times in SQL

Tags: sql, date, time, between

I need to run a query that finds all login dates (`dd/mm/yyyy`) and times (`hh.mm`) that occurred between 2am yesterday and 2am today. The login time in the database is formatted as `mm-dd-yyyy hh.mm.ss`.

I have tried multiple `select` and `between` queries that either return data on the wrong day or outside the time spans.

Comment: What is the structure of your data, what are the queries that you've tried, what was the result, and what was the expected result?

Comment: What datatype are your datetimes stored in? Are they stored as string data, or a native date/time format?

Comment: Ive tried Select login from employeelogins where login between datepart(hh, getdate()-1) > 2 and datepart(hh, getdate()) > 2... I'm new to this and am now completely confused..

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product.... and these kind of functions are very often vendor-specific...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information that you provided, I can only give a generic example:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN '08-15-2011 02:00:00' AND '08-16-2011 02:00:00'
```

**EDIT**

Per a good suggestion from the comments, here is a reusable version:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '02:00'
                     AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '02:00'
```

Comment: What if I have to get a time between other dates and time?

Comment: I am sorry, its not my question and I did not downvote. I hardly downvote to any question. But my point is yesterday and today can be different dates. What if I have to run this query tomorrow?

Comment: @Vinay, sorry, I jumped the gun and I apologize. You make a good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I need, however the specific dates wont exist as the query needs to run daily looking for the record between 2am 'yesterday' and 2am 'today'...

Comment: @Withdalot, the SQL under the EDIT section will fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @Vinay - Thats my exact issue. Thanks for assisting to clarify.

Comment: @James - sorry James I still have no idea how this would work

Comment: @Withdalot, Did you try it? `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '02:00'` will return the current date at 2 AM. `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '02:00'` will return yesterdays date at 2 AM. Please give it a try.

Comment: James this is great and it works a treat. Thanks so much for your help... Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. @Vinay, thanks again for clarifying the need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(your_date, '%m-%d-%Y %H.%i.%s') BETWEEN
DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y'), '%m-%d-%Y'), INTERVAL 22 HOUR) AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y'), '%m-%d-%Y'), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

I'm sure there's a better way though.

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't return any records if we use as follows...

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '02:00'
                 AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '02:00'
```

We are using between clause so the oldest date should be first and the query becomes as follows...

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '02:00'
                 AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '02:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also help you out

```
where pt.status in (1) 
    and pt.is_visible in ('t') 
    and pt.merchant in (0) 
    and (date(pt.created_at+'05:30') >= current_date-2 
            and extract(hour from(pt.created_at+'05:30')) >=17)
    and ((pt.created_at+'05:30') <= current_date-1
            and extract(hour from(pt.created_at+'05:30')) <=17)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use these tips :

```
SET @start = CURDATE() - interval 1 DAY + interval 2 HOUR;
SET @end = CURDATE() + interval 2 HOUR;
```

And :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN @start AND @end
```